# changing coupling between two signals detection

Tags: matlab

I'm studying the coupling between two ECG signals, I can find the phase shift between both of them and plot it. The figure below shows the psi which is obtained from the phase shift between the two signals.
[image]
What I need to do next is try o quantify the coupling between the signals, the more horizontal portions are better in terms of coherence or coupling. What's the best way to detect the behaviour of the psi output and give me an indicator of how coherent are the two signal in every portion (window) of the signal?

I tried to find the gradient or the derivatie of the signal and I got what is shown in the fourth subplot (phase locking). Any ideas as to what's the best way to study the behavior of psi?

Comment: Are you interested in phase shifts of 180°? It seems strange to me that the gradient is the smallest in the middle area. Some low pass filtering may also be useful. What have you plotted? The gradient or the difference between two consecutive data points? Are they equally spaced?

Comment: No I'm interested in the phase shift of the first ECG with respect to the other, after getting that shift we take "mod(delta,2*pi)/2*pi;" to get psi. The first and second plots are my ECG signals, the third is psi and the fourth is an attempt to quantify psi (in this case it was the gradient). I've also tried a previous method called phase locking and it didn't give me what I wanted. finally the ECG signals are roughly equally apart if the pulse is regular, but this is not always the case here, which is why I'm having a changing phase throughout the figure.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in trying the cross-correlation function xcorr in matlab:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html

See the first example "Delay Between Two Correlated Signals" on the MathWorks link.  You can do this on the whole signal or even break it up into many windows to try and help with the non-regularity.

You might also consider using a spectrogram for analysis which will tell you how the frequency spectrum of your signal changes over time.  I haven't done this sort of thing myself but it seems like if there are particular frequency features you are interested in you could compare them using a spectrogram either before or after correcting a delay between the signals using xcorr.

Comment: I looked at what you suggested, but I wan't to point out that my two ECG signals aren't from the same source, one is from the mother and the other one is from the fetus; their frequency is different of course but they are in sync often. As for the spectrogram, I tried implementing it on my signal and I was able to see a changing behaviour or color with time, but I want to plot it vs time so I can link the changes in the histogram to the corresponding psi region